# Adding text stops Custom GL Item from Rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm rendering a custom OpenGL Item, and on top of that I would like to add some widgets.

So far, it's working fine. This is what it looks like.

[image]

However, now I am trying to add a `Text` item to the OpenGL via:

```
Rectangle{
    id: logoTextBox
    x: logoButton.x + logoButton.width
    y: logoButton.y
    width: 200
    height: logoButton.height
    color: "#EEEEEE"

    Text{
        id: logoVersionBlurb
        y: 10
        x: 10
        font.pointSize: 8
        text: "Ver 1.0"
        color: "black"
    }

    Text{
        id: logoNameBlurb
        y: 20
        x: 10
        font.pointSize:  14
        font.bold: true
        text: "Please work"
    }
}
```

and It looks like this: 
[image]

I still want the OpenGL to render, but I want the `Text` to appear overlayed above it. Any ideas?

I'm creating my `GLContext` like this in QML:

```
MyGLWidget{
   id: glWidget
}
```

And here is the relevant method from the C++ file

```
void MyGLWidget::sync()
{
    if (!m_renderer) {
        m_renderer = new MyGLRenderer();
        connect(window(), SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), m_renderer, SLOT(paint()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    }
    m_renderer->setViewportSize(window()->size() * window()->devicePixelRatio());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found a solution. I set the text's renderType to NativeRendering, and that caused the Triangle to render correctly.

```
    Text{
        id:sizeDialogXText
        color: "white"
        y: sizeDialogTitleText.y + 20
        x: sizeDialogTitleText.x
        text: "X"
        font.pointSize: 12
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering //This is the important line
    }
```

Comment: That's a workaround, not even close to a solution. In your slot are you leaving the GL state as you found it, or are you tampering it? If so, call QQuickWindow::resetOpenGLState.